# Join DELETE in MySql? How to?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have this:

```
$query="DELETE FROM classified, $sql_table WHERE classified.ad_id = '$id' AND classified.classified_id = $sql_table.classified_id AND classified.poster_password='$pass'";
```

I get this error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE classified.ad_id = 'Bmw_M3_E46_Full_29920' AND classified.cla' at line 1`

Any help?

As you can see the $sql_table is linked to the classifieds table with the fields `classified_id`
I need to JOIN DELETE somehow.

Basically classified table is the main table, then every category has its own tables with vehicle data. classified table has a field called classified_id which is the same as the

Here is the full query echoed:

```
DELETE FROM classified, vehicles WHERE classified.ad_id = 'Bmw_M3_E46_410811305' AND classified.classified_id = vehicles.classified_id AND classified.poster_password='some_password'
```

Why isn't this working, Should it be so hard to delete from multiple tables?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE a, b FROM
classified as a, $sql_table as b
WHERE
classified.ad_id = '$id' 
AND classified.classified_id = $sql_table.classified_id 
AND classified.poster_password='$pass'";
```

Source: [Source](http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Join/DeleterecordsfromtwotablesusingJOIN.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) website indicates that you may need to declare your tables after the DELETE statement:

**Multiple-table syntax:**

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
  tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
  FROM table_references
  [WHERE where_condition]
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters check syntax for [multiple table delete](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)
You need to specify tables from which to delete

```
DELETE classified.*, vehicles.* FROM classified, vehicles
```

Answer (score 0):

i just has detect something but didn't know its really working or not, try to put what you want to tied from two tables first like this:

```
 DELETE FROM classified, vehicles WHERE classified.classified_id = vehicles.classified_id
AND classified.ad_id = 'Bmw_M3_E46_410811305' 
AND classified.poster_password='some_password'
```

then only what exact value in the column you want to delete. please try n revert.