# how to delete from three tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, sql-delete

room table>>
room_id , standard

guest table>>
guest_id, guest type

booking table >>
booking_id ,room_id,guest_id

my question is>Delete the records of guest who have booked ‘Deluxe’ rooms.
(deluxe is a type of  standard )

please help ?to make a query i am a beginner  for SQL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Join DELETE in MySql? How to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685211/join-delete-in-mysql-how-to)

Comment: nope i need to join this three table  first

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you just want to delete from the `booking` table.  I'm also assuming you need to specify *something* from the `guest` table, otherwise you wouldn't need the third table at all.

```
DELETE b
FROM booking b
INNER JOIN room r
    ON r.room_id = b.room_id
INNER JOIN guest g
    ON g.guest_id = b.guest_id
WHERE r.standard = 'Deluxe'
    AND g.field = ????
```

That's a MS SQL extension, however.  The ANSI way to do it is:

```
DELETE FROM booking b
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM room r
        WHERE r.room_id = b.room_id
            AND r.standard = 'Deluxe')
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM guest g
        WHERE g.guest_id = b.room_id
            AND g.field = ????)
```

Comment: room table>> room_id , standard

guest table>> guest_id, guest type

booking table >> booking_id ,room_id,guest_id  <<<< these are my tables and columns  i need to delete "of guest who have booked ‘Deluxe’ rooms" that mean i need to delete gust table records ..

Comment: @sandy I don't know.  "of guest who have booked ‘Deluxe’ rooms" is unclear to me.  Logically, to me, only deleting from `booking` makes the most sense.  Why would you need to delete from `room`?  Does not having a room booked mean the room doesn't exist?  Why would you need to delete from `guest`?  Does removing 'Deluxe' bookings mean the guest can't remain in the system for future use?  What if they have other room standards booked?  The only deletion that makes sense to me is booking.

Comment: @sandy If, on the other hand, you really need to delete from `room` or `guest` as well as `booking`, then you'll need to use multiple delete statements.  MS SQL Server will not allow you to delete from multiple tables in a single statement.